# Oauth not working properly- Emulation and Debug Mode- Intel XDK

Tags: html, oauth-2.0, intel-xdk

I am a newbie for intel xdk and coding as whole. I am working on Oauth2 . I am using the response type as Token. I am able to generate the redirect URI with auth token. When I call the google appscript webapp appended by the auth token, it works in emulator (sometimes). For this I call a function and pass webapp url along with auth token. Then I use command window.open(URL) to open the webapp. However, this do not work when "Test" or Debug mode and the script stops at the redirect uri page. Thus I understand that token is generated but the webapp is not getting called. Please help how to fix it.

Code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
      <script src="intelxdk.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        var OAUTHURL    =   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
        var VALIDURL    =   'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
        var SCOPE       =   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';
        var CLIENTID    =   '****************************';
        var REDIRECT    =   'http://example.com/oauth2callback'
        var LOGOUT      =   'http://accounts.google.com/Logout';
        var TYPE        =   'token';
        var _url        =   OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
        var acToken;
        var tokenType;
        var expiresIn;
        var user;
        var loggedIn    =   false;

        function login() {
            var win         =   window.open(_url); 
            var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
                try {
                    console.log(win.document.URL);
                    if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                        var url =   win.document.URL;
                        acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                        tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                        expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                        getUserInfo(acToken);                   
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                ;}
            }, 500);    
        }

function gup(url, name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\#&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( url );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }


function getUserInfo() {
           var url_token=  'https://script.google.com/macros/s/****************************/exec?access_token=' + acToken;
            window.open(url_token);
        }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href='#' onClick='login(); id="loginText"'> Click here to login </a>

    <div id='uName'></div>
    <img src='' id='imgHolder'/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is oauth2 example to use with Intel XDK, add InAppBrowser plugin and test: https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2

Comment: Thanks Rakshith, I had earlier tried your github code earlier with Appbrowser plugin and it was not working. I am not sure, what did I changed. But voila, it is working now!! Thanks a ton.. really happy!

Comment: @krisrak Hi Rakshit, i am facing another problem. Each time i reopen my app, i have to signin again and again. What can be the work around of that? Thanks in advance

Comment: once u get access_token, u have to save in local storage or somewhere and you app should use that if available, if not u have to show login button